# Google Maps API V3 Android very slow with many markers?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

In Google Maps API for Android V3, the map becomes very slow and laggy when there are many markers on the map. Dragging the map a few inches takes 2 -3 seconds. I looked online for some answers but most of them seemed to be either clustering solutions or Javascript specific solutions.

Does anyone know how to speed of Google Maps API for Android with many markers?

Thank you

Comment: I have the same problem, but only on certain phones. All the markers render, but user can barely even scroll the map. Other phones loading the exact same number of markers is smooth.